# Untiy List.Add prevents a sprite update on Android

Tags: c#, android, list, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a method that gets called when a button is pressed,

```
private List<Page> _pages = new List<Page>();
public void LoadKern(int requestedKern)
    {
        TextAsset pages = Resources.Load("kern" + requestedKern) as TextAsset;

        JSONArray jsonPages = JSON.Parse(pages.text)["pages"].AsArray;

        foreach (JSONNode page in jsonPages)
        {
            _pages.Add(new Page(page["image"], page["text"]));
        }

        ImageSpriteRenderer.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(_pages[currentPage].image);
        TextSpriteRenderer.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(_pages[currentPage].text);
    }
```

The code works perfect when running it in the simulator but whenever I deploy it to an android device or use the [Untiy Remote 4](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html) it no longer updates the sprites.

Whenever I remove this line and set the resource manually, it does update when the button is pressed.

```
_pages.Add(new Page(page["image"], page["text"]));
```

It seems very odd that it does work on a desktop but not on Android, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Most likely, the call Resources.Load<> fails due to the file path problem.

Comment: @David, Is there a difference with Resources.Load<>() on Android? It does work perfectly on Windows.

Comment: Yes, quite different. I frequently encounter such problems, e.g a Text, Json file works on Unity Editor, but fails to work in Android/iOS.

Comment: @David Are there any solutions to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it difficult to put it in the comment, so I write it as an answer here.

The simplest approach to verify this a problem due to the Resource.Load<>, is to add below code:

```
TextAsset pages = Resources.Load("kern" + requestedKern) as TextAsset;
Debug.Load(pages + "are Loading");  // to see if it is really loaded successfully
```

Connect your device and open the adb log, filter the message with "are loading".
If you see pages are *null*, then it is clear that Resource.Load<> is the culprit.

If it is Resource.Load<> problem, you can consider using [StreamingAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html):

> Any files placed in a folder called StreamingAssets in a Unity project will be copied **verbatim** to a particular folder on the target machine. You can retrieve the folder using the **Application.streamingAssetsPath** property. It’s always best to use Application.streamingAssetsPath to get the location of the StreamingAssets folder, it will always point to the correct location on the platform where the application is running.

On Android, you should use:

```
path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";
```

I suspect that your loading the text assets is carried out at runtime, when you package the app, the text assets are not read, and it might be excluded from the project, as Unity considers this "not used". When you run the app on Android, it is natural that it fails.

Using StreamingAssets approach, you force Unity to copy the text assets "verbatim" which assures it is accessible at runtime!